# Get child process id of already running process

Tags: c, node.js, process

I'm calling an external program (via pty.js in node) that when it runs it spawns a child process. When the parent process finishes it leaves the child running for quit some time (orphan). I can get the id of the parent process, but would like to get the id of the child that is spawned so I can kill it when the parent quits.

I don't believe there is any way in node to achieve this, so is there anything in C that allows you to get the id of a child, knowing only the parent id. Everything I have found so far relates to getting the child id from the fork() but the fork took place in the external program.

Alternatively I guess I could make a call to ps or pstree / something similar and parse the output but feels like a bit of a hack.

### EDIT

It's not nice but I've come up with this so far:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int id = atoi(argv[1]);
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < INT_MAX; i++) {
    if(i != id && getpgid(i) == id) {
      printf("Process %d, is a child of %d", i, id);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In node.js you can do it via `child_process` library. There is a [pid](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid) member function that returns the spawned child's pid. E.g.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    grep  = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

console.log('Spawned child pid: ' + grep.pid);
grep.stdin.end();
```

You can also kill the child process with [kill](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal).

The `pty.js` does a fork with a pseudo terminal, which is useful if emulating terminal. Otherwise you should use `child_process` to spawn/fork new processes.

Comment: I need to emulate the terminal in for this program so it has to use pty.js unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add this code at the end of parent process :

```
int i ;
while(1)
{
    i = wait();//wait child exit
    if(i == -1)//if there is no child process 
       break;
}
```

If you can't . Then you need do nothing!

**Here is the problem:**

If the parent process finished but the children process didn't, those children process called :"**orphan process**" **NOT** "**zombie**". A "zombie process" means a child process finished while the patent process still runs, and the parent process didn't handle the child process's  aftermath.

Since system will set "`init`" become the parent of  all "orphan process".The `init` process will deal with everything . So you need do nothing.!!

Comment: @gratz I have modifed my anwser.  Now I think you need do nothing. :)

Comment: Eventually the orphan gets cleaned up but it can take quite a long time. I've added an update to the OP which I'll do some more testing with.